# Is the original Zelda available for the Wii?

Tags: the-legend-of-zelda

I loved the old gold-cartridge Zelda, and I've played (and own) the latest Zelda adventure where you can go trotting off through a fairly realistic 3D world, including swimming and they make full use of the wiimotes.

Is there a version of the gold-cartridge for the Wii? Where can I get one, if so, and how much does it cost?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, the original Zelda is available on Nintendo's Virtual Console.  I believe the majority of the NES games are 500 Wii points.

To obtain any Virtual Console games, open the Wii Shop Channel and choose the Virtual Console icon.  You can browse the games by system or genre.  Once purchased, the game is downloaded to your Wii and appears in one of the channel screens.  For NES games, you can get away with using the Wii remote turned sideways as your controller, since you only need two buttons.  For SNES and up, you will want a Classic Controller, since that gives you all the buttons you need.

Comment: I did not even know that there was a Virtual Console. Guess it shows how often I play my wii eh? Thanks, I'll have to check that out for sure!

Comment: If you have a GameCube controller, you can use that instead of buying the Classic Controller. The button layout isn't always ideal, though.

Comment: Thanks @Adeese I will keep that in mind. But I've got a classic controller already, so that's not a big deal. I'm just stoked that I now get to play old classics. Now I just need to get that 55" widescreen and I'll look like a total boss playing 8-bit games ;)